# Array becomes undefined when passed to function React js , socket.io

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to pass an array to a function and use it, somehow the array becomes undefined when passed to the function i don't know what i'm doing wrong. I'm using react js and Socket.io the code in question is below:

```js
socket.on(PRIVATE_MESSAGE, ({reciever, sender})=>{
  if(reciever in connectedUsers){
      var users = [reciever, sender]
      console.log("users: " + users )
   const newChat = factories.createNewConversation(`${reciever}&${sender}`, users)
      }
 })
```

Here i'm passing the users array to the function createNewConversation, when i print the array before i pass it, it works fine.

```js
function createNewConversation(Messages, Name, Users) {
 var conversationID = uuidv4()
 console.log("user found: " + Users)
              .
              .
              .
 }
```

here when i try to print the Users array it says its undefined. I've looked around but couldn't find an answer. any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `createNewConversation` accept 3 arguments not 2, call it like this `factories.createNewConversation(\`${reciever}&${sender}\`, null, users)`

Comment: @Farnabaz This is the answer.

Comment: I'm so stupid thank you